# How to use python build script with teamcity CI?

Tags: c++, python, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am currently researching using the TeamCity CI software for our comapanies CI automation needs but have had trouble finding information about using different build scripts with TeamCity. We have C++ projects that need to have build/test automation and we currently have licenses for TeamCity. I have looked into using scons for the build automation but havent been able to find much information about using a python build script with TeamCity. If anyone could provide information about this to a CI beginner would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use TeamCity to run our acceptance test suite (which uses Robot Framework - done in python).

Getting it to run was as simple as wrapping the python call with a very simple NAnt script. It does 2 things:

1. Uses an [exec task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) to run python with the script as an argument.
2. Gets the xml output from the build and [transforms](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/style.html) it into [something teamcity can understand](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-teamcityinfo.xml).

There are probably tasks to run python scripts directly with NAnt but we've not had to use them - it was pretty easy to get up and running. You could do the same sort of thing using Ant or whatever depending on what your platform was.